# Datagrid Column Width using VB6

Tags: datagrid, vb6

I am using VB6. The code below doesn't work. Also, multi select in VB6 datagrid.

How to set datagrid column width?

```
With DataGrid1
    .Columns(0).Width = "7000"
    .Columns(1).Width = "3000"
End With
```

Comment: Is there something like Autosize? Then you have to set it to false.

Comment: When you bind the DataGrid it sets column widths based on the field definitions.  After binding you can change the widths.  I don't think there is any facility to "multiselect" rows, you are probably using the wrong control.  Consider one of the flexgrid controls instead.

Comment: On second thought a ListView might make more sense.  Those offer multiselect and in "report view" present a grid-like display.

Answer (score 0):

Set column width of a DataGrid in Visual Basic 6.0  by using columns width parameter.

For example:

```
DataGrid1.Columns(0).width = 1000
```

It sets the width of the first column as 1000